# IIS w3wp process failing unexpected

Tags: iis, hangfire

I have setup a hangfire service with a server and a dashboard and I've deployed this to IIS , I also created a Db called "HangfireServerDb" and I've started the IIS server. The hangfire server started and created the require schema and tables and also for a period all jobs ran without any issues.

At some point , after the service run without any issues for hours I'm getting this , and I have no idea what it actually mean or what might cause it.

> Application: w3wp.exe
> CoreCLR Version: 6.0.2623.60508
> .NET Version: 6.0.26
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.AggregateException: One or more hosted services failed to stop. (A task was canceled.)
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
> at Hangfire.Processing.TaskExtensions.WaitOneAsync(WaitHandle waitHandle, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken token) in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.Core\Processing\TaskExtensions.cs:line 96
> at Hangfire.Processing.BackgroundDispatcher.WaitAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.Core\Processing\BackgroundDispatcher.cs:line 82
> at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundProcessingServer.WaitForShutdownAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.Core\Server\BackgroundProcessingServer.cs:line 148
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.WaitForShutdownAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at HangfireDashboard.WebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\CI_Data\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\ea4fb37391903d0f\Services\HangfireDashboard\Program.cs:line 22
> at HangfireDashboard.WebApi.Program.(String[] args)

The IIS app pool is configured with

Start Mode : AlwaysRunning
Recycling > Regular Time Interval : 0
Managed Pipeline Mode : Integrated

Comment: Clearly you should read `...\src\Hangfire.Core\Server\BackgroundProcessingServer.cs:line 148` as the exception call stack indicated. It's an open source project, so no secret is hidden from you.

Comment: Ok, but how can this help me since it is not under my control ?

Comment: According to the stack information you provided, you can see that the root cause of the exception is a TaskCanceledException. It is thrown in the TaskExtensions.WaitOneAsync method in Hangfire's code. This method is called by BackgroundDispatcher.WaitAsync, which eventually causes problems with BackgroundProcessingServer.WaitForShutdownAsync, which then affects the Host.StopAsync method, etc.

Comment: Through this stack trace, you can trace the path of the exception and find the code location of the root cause of the exception. Here, the problem seems to occur during the stopping of Hangfire's background tasks, causing one task to be canceled and ultimately causing the entire application to shut down abnormally. The reasons for the cancellation of the mission may be multifactorial and require further investigation. If Hangfire has a built-in logging system, check the relevant log files.